# Symfony form - Client with 2 phones unique validation

Tags: php, symfony

I want to validate as unique 2 columns of a table at the same time. I have 2 phones per client on 2 separate columns like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ClientRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="client", 
 *    uniqueConstraints={
 *        @UniqueConstraint(name="phone_second_phone_constraint", 
 *            columns={"phone", "second_phone"})
 *    })
 * @UniqueEntity("email")
 * @UniqueEntity("phone")
 * @UniqueEntity("second_phone")
 */
 class Client {

     /**
      * @ORM\Column(name="phone", type="phone_number", length=50, unique=true, nullable=true)
      * @AssertPhoneNumber(type="any")
      */
     protected $phone = null;

     /**
      * @ORM\Column(name="second_phone", type="phone_number", length=50, unique=true, nullable=true)
      * @AssertPhoneNumber(type="any")
      */
     protected $second_phone = null;
 }
```

**I don't want to have the phone repeated on any column or any client.**

Any ideas on how to achieve this please?

Thanks and kind regards,
David M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand correctly you want when a phone number is used in `phone` or `second_phone` to not be able to get reused.

For that reason a unique key with combination of those two fields won't help you because it will only violate the unique constraint when the same phone numbers appear in the same exact fields e.g phone=X and second_phone=Y you will be able to save phone=Y and second_phone=X.

To avoid that you will have to create a custom constraint that will check if the phone number exists already in the database.

[Here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html) is the documentation on how to create and use a constraint in symfony.

So your code will look like this

**your custom constraint**

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
* @Annotation
*/
class UniquePhoneNumber extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'The phone number "{{ phoneNumber }}" is already in use.';
}
```

**your constraint validator**

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class UniquePhoneNumberValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }        

    public function validate($phoneNumber, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        $client = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Client::class)->findByPhoneNumber($phoneNumber);

        if (!is_null($client)) {
            $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                ->setParameter('{{ phoneNumber }}',$phoneNumber)
                ->addViolation();
        }
    }
}
```

**somewhere in your Client repository**

```
public function findByPhoneNumber(string $phoneNumber): ?Client
{
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder('c');
    $qb->select('c')
        ->where('c.phone = :phone OR c.second_phone = :phone')
        ->setParameter('phone',$phoneNumber)
        ->setMaxResults(1);

    return $qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
}
```

then use your new `validator` on phone and `second_phone`, on how to do that [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html#using-the-new-validator) is a link, it depends on where you will place your constraint classes, but in general you will have to do this

- import the constraints, `use App\Validator\Constraints as CustomAssert;`
- if you are using annotations, add the annotation above the field `@CustomAssert\UniquePhoneNumber`

---

Note you will have to add the namespaces for the constraint and the validator and also if you place the constraints in a different folder that App\Validator\Constraints you will have to adapt the use statement in your entity file

Comment: Thanks you very much!